# Kendo UI Template notation for encoding doesn't seem to work

Tags: html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-template

According to the [Kendo UI template documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview), you can use either the `#=Field#` or `#:Field#` notation, with the `#:Field#` notation encoding the text.  However, I cannot seem to get this to work.

I created a field in my model that just returned a string, `<b>Todd</b>`.  Then, I used the template like this:

```
<a href="/page.aspx?path=#=Field#"></a>
```

and also like this:

```
<a href="/page.aspx?path=#:Field#"></a>
```

In BOTH cases, the output was

```
<a href="/page.aspx?path=<b>Todd<b>"></a>
```

While I would expect that for the #=Field# notation, for the #:Field# notation, I was expecting:

```
<a href="/page.aspx?path=%3Cb%3ETodd%3C/b%3E"></a>
```

Any ideas on why this isn't working like I am expecting?

Comment: Could you post the rest of your code that uses your template? That will help us give you a better answer.

Comment: not sure what else you need to see?  the <a> markup above with the template is what gets passed to the kendo grid, and the <a> markup above is what ends up getting rendered.  I was expecting #=Field# and #:Field# to do two different things, and they don't.  I'm just wondering why.

Comment: in the link you post, there is already an example and an important notes saying that the "HTML encoding is useful when you want to avoid rendering HTML tags in your templates. It escapes the HTML tags in your data and renders the tags as a string", its not like a HTML encoder/decoder

Comment: @himawan_r then how do i get kendo to HTML encode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got a response from Kendo.  They said do use #:encodeURI(Field)#, #:encodeURIComponent(Field)#, or #:escape(Field)# instead of #:Field# to get the result I was looking for.

I tested that out, and it did work for me.